# Write data to a server-side .xml file using either javascript or Php

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

I have a site based in html and javascript.

on the site, data is taken from a server-side .xml file. THIS WORKS PERFECT!

Also I want the user to be able to enter data into a field and have that data saved on another sever-side .xml file. I CAN'T GET THIS TO WORK! I have the data stored in variables and ready to pass to php but can't get any php code to work. (I am new to php)

I have changed the permissions of the .xml file on the sever to read and write.

I have been scanning the web for the last few days to try and get some code to work, but i have not got anything working yet.

Can Anyone help please?

Comment: Show us a sample of your code which doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

POST all the data present in the variables to a PHP script using a [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call.
Once the data is sent to the PHP script, using [simpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml) you can dynamically generate a xml file and save it in the server using [file_put contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) .

Comment: you can use a simple html form as well!

Comment: AJAX just makes sure your page is not redirected/refreshed...and the process happens without the user being bothered.

Comment: Well this was an example i was trying to get working but couldn't.

Comment: <?php
function writeElement()
 {
  $xdoc = new DomDocument;
  $xdoc->Load('sample.xml');
  $candidate = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('candidate')->item(0);
  $newElement = $xdoc ->createElement('candidatedesignation');
  $txtNode = $xdoc ->createTextNode ("Project Manager");
  $newElement -> appendChild($txtNode);
  $candidate -> appendChild($newElement);
  $test = $xdoc->save('sample.xml');
  echo "<B>Data Appended<B>"
 }
?>

Comment: Thanks Selvam Palanimalai, thats great help, I will get to work on it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: sure! feel free to ask questions :)

Comment: Got it all sorted thanks a million for your help, In future if you know anyone who needs help with the same thing, send them on to this site.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/ajax there is one mistake in this code though, in the if statement, if(req) { req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange; req.open("GET", url + '?' + params, true); req.send(null); return true;   the line req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange; is not needed.

Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Ok i have one last question about this. I have the AJAX working, the javascript/html page invokes a .php file. The php file saves data into an .xml file.

The one problem i have is that in php i cannot seem to get the data sent by the javascript. currently i just have the php saving random information into the .xml file

Comment: <?php
 //This line will load the XML file.
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("commentsW.xml"); 

 //In this line it create a SimpleXMLElement object with the source of the XML file.
 $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
 
 //The following lines will add a new child and others child inside the previous child created.
 $person = $sxe->addChild("COMMENT");
 $person->addChild("DATA", $params);
 
 //This next line will overwrite the original XML file with new data added
 $sxe->asXML("commentsW.xml"); 
?>

Comment: here is the JavaScript function

Comment: function callPHP(url, params) {
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
   try { 
    req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
   } 
   catch(e) { 
    req = false;
   } 
  } 
  else if(window.ActiveXObject){  try 
    { 
    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 
   catch(e) 
    { try { 
  req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
     } 
     catch(e) 
     { 
     req = false; 
     } 
    } 
   } 
   if(req) { 
    req.open("POST", url, true); 
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    req.send(params); 
    return true; 
   }
   return false; 
  }

Comment: Sorry for these looking so bad. i dont know how to formatt this code properly on this site...